# How to store bit value into sql server DB from frontend?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a bit field in my table which can store 0 or 1.

In my webpage I declare like

```
<label>Do we have your permission to send your cell a text</label>
<div>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ctrluuSendSMS" id="ctrluuSendSMS" value="1">Yes</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ctrluuSendSMS" id="ctrluuSendSMS" value="0">No</label>
</div>
```

while I am submitting the form I got the following error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean
```

please help me out how to declare and how to store into DB

Comment: Showing the HTML doesn't help us understand how the insert is being performed. Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try to pass the bit value to the Database as an int, not a string(convert in code and then pass to StoredProc/ORM as an integer parameter).

(As alroc commented, can we see the sql code?)

I'm assuming your table looks something like

```
Create Table MyTable
(
 SomePK int not null identity(1,1),
 MyBitValue bit
)
```

So your insert/update statement would look like

```
Declare @MyParam int = 1 -- where 1(or 0) is an integer, not a string
Declare @MyParam2 bit = 1 
Insert Into MyTable(MyBitValue)Values(@MyParam)
Insert Into MyTable(MyBitValue)Values(@MyParam2)

Select * From MyTable

Set @MyParam = 0
Set @MyParam2 = 0
Update MyTable Set MyBitValue = @MyParam Where SomePK = 1
Update MyTable Set MyBitValue = @MyParam2 Where SomePK = 2

Select * from MyTable
```

**Edit**:  I've updated my example to show using both an int and a bit

Comment: Why pass it as an int when sql has a bit type?

Comment: You could do that, and it would be perfectly valid.  I've always used int though(cast/converted the boolean in C# to an int).  Updated answer w/bit

Answer (score 0):

Use "True" and "False" as opposed to "1" and "0" for the value attributes of the Input elements.

```
<label>Do we have your permission to send your cell a text</label>
<div>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ctrluuSendSMS" id="ctrluuSendSMS" value="True">Yes</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ctrluuSendSMS" id="ctrluuSendSMS" value="False">No</label>
</div>
```

numeric strings would have to be converted to numeric values before being converted to boolean

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToByte("1")) = True
```

but "True" and "False" will convert directly.

```
Convert.ToBoolean("True") = True
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx